# Can't find the name of this anime for the life of me!

Tags: sakura-diaries

The anime starts off with the guy in a hotel room, he turned on the TV and got a knock at the door. It turned out to be a girl that at the moment he didn't know but I think she turned out to be his cousin? They almost had sex because she seduced him and he thought she was a random call girl but he realized at the last second who she was I think and he kicked her out wearing no clothes lol.

Then, he started taking a bunch of college entrance exams failing all of them I think... he ran into some beautiful woman who I think went to the Tokyo U, or some kind of prestigious University that he couldn't hope to get into. But he went and took the exam anyway and that's about all I remember.

The art style was older, might have been late 90s early 2000's for all I know. Any leads? MC had longish black hair. I don't think it was a hentai or anything. I tried searching and literally nothing fits that description, so weird lol. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anime you're looking for is [Sakura Diaries](http://myanimelist.net/anime/818/Sakura_Tsuushin).

> A Keio University (one of the top three colleges in Japan) exam candidate, Touma Inaba, is interupted when a cute young girl, Urara Kasuga, arrives at his hotel room door. She later turns out to be his cousin who he barely remembers from his childhood. Urara, who had felt something special for him (an other-than-cousinly-love), invites Touma to live with her since he has no place to stay other than the hotel room.

[image: Sakura Diaries]

Comment: Exactly the one I was looking for! Thanks!